# mysql Server version: 5.0.95 datediff timediff not working

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

Latest version of mysql server 5.7 and I am using 5.0 .
in Case mysql Server version: 5.0.95 datediff  timediff not working any help suggestion are welcome.
May be a small error in approach.

```
mysql> describe agent_idel_time;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0                   |       |
| holdtime        | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| hold_max        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| hold_min        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| hold_avg        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| hold_start_time | datetime         | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| hold_end_time   | datetime         | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| htime           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
mysql> select * from agent_idel_time \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             id: 1
       holdtime: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
       hold_max: 55
       hold_min: 5
       hold_avg: 30
hold_start_time: 2016-06-30 15:10:00
  hold_end_time: 2016-06-30 15:12:00
          htime: 00:00:00
*************************** 2. row ***************************
             id: 2
       holdtime: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
       hold_max: 57
       hold_min: 7
       hold_avg: 32
hold_start_time: 2016-06-30 17:10:00
  hold_end_time: 2016-06-30 17:12:00
          htime: 00:00:00
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
No query specified

mysql>
mysql>
mysql> UPDATE agent_idel_time SET htime = time_format(TIMEDIFF( `hold_end_time` , `hold_start_time` ) ,'%H:%m:%s');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> select * from agent_idel_time \G; 
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             id: 1
       holdtime: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
       hold_max: 55
       hold_min: 5
       hold_avg: 30
hold_start_time: 2016-06-30 15:10:00
  hold_end_time: 2016-06-30 15:12:00
          htime: 00:00:00
*************************** 2. row ***************************
             id: 2
       holdtime: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
       hold_max: 57
       hold_min: 7
       hold_avg: 32
hold_start_time: 2016-06-30 17:10:00
  hold_end_time: 2016-06-30 17:12:00
          htime: 00:00:00
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
No query specified
```

Comment: Uograde it. 5.1 was released thirteen years ago, and 5.7 three years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the format string for the `time_format` function wrong.

*Minutes, numeric (00..59)* is **`%i`**, not **`%m`** (which is *Month, numeric (00..12)*) so change your update statement to:

```
UPDATE agent_idel_time 
SET htime = time_format(TIMEDIFF(`hold_end_time`, `hold_start_time`) ,'%H:%i:%s');
```

Or you could use **`'%T'`** which is *time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)* instead.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for the format codes.

Comment: mysql> UPDATE agent_idel_time SET htime = time_format(TIMEDIFF( `hold_end_time` , `hold_start_time` ) ,'%H:%m:%s');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
---output ----not as per expected ---

Comment: mysql> select * from agent_idel_time ;                                                                    +----+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+

|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       55 |        5 |       30 | 2016-06-30 15:10:00 | 2016-06-30 15:12:00 | 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       57 |        7 |       32 | 2016-06-30 17:10:00 | 2016-06-30 17:12:00 | 00:00:00 |

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @HardikK.Chauhan In your first comment above you are still using %m for minutes, not %i , did you miss the change or paste the wrong query? Look at this for a working example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/346370/2

Comment: mysql>  UPDATE agent_idel_time SET htime = time_format(TIMEDIFF( `hold_end_time` , `hold_start_time` ) ,'%H:%i:%s');


|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       55 |        5 |       30 | 2016-06-30 15:10:00 | 2016-06-30 15:12:00 | 00:02:00 |
|  2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       57 |        7 |       32 | 2016-06-30 17:10:00 | 2016-06-30 17:12:00 | 00:02:00 |
+----+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
MANY MANY THANKS TO @jpw @Barmar and stackoveflow